# Confusion related to Taylor series approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion

I found this Taylor series approximation given by

$f(x_{\alpha}) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)'(x_{\alpha}-x) + o(||x_{\alpha}-x||)$. I didn't get how this $o(||x_{\alpha}-x||)$ term came from. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: I'm sure it means $o(\lvert x_\alpha - x \vert^2)$.

Comment: Do you know little-oh notation?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an expansion in several variables.  It is entirely analogous to the expansion in 1 variable.  You will recall that the one variable expansion is

f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + R(x) where R(x) is an error term.  From the definition of derivative we know that $R(x)/(x-a) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow a$.  That means R(x) must must be $o(x-a)^2$.

Notationally nothing changes if you go to n dimensions. Better, every concept in the 1 dimensional case has an n-dimensional analogue. So the error term will be of the same order in n dimensions as it is in 1.